# How to define a variable as another variable divided by two?

Tags: tikz-pgf, calc

I would like to define a variable `\j` in a loop `\foreach \i in { 2, 4, 6}` and use `\j` to labels of the nodes.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{balance,complexity,pgfplots,tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]

        \def \half {0.5};

        \foreach \i in { 2, 4, 6}
        {
            \def \j {\i*\half};
            \node[draw=none] at (\i,0) {$X_{\j}$};
            \node[draw=none] at (-\i,0) {$X'_{\j}$};
        }


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to get this output:

[image]

Instead, I get this:

[image]

How can I use mathematical operators to modify the label of a node?

Comment: Isn't it easier doing `\node[draw=none] at (2*\i,0) {$X_{\i}$};` with `\foreach \i in {1,2,3}`?

Comment: @egreg That is true, but I need the division or multiplication by 0.5 for a different reason.

Comment: @egreg I just realized that I could also use the method that you suggested :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `\pgfmath` macros (`\pgfmathsetmacro` for float calculations and `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` if you only want the integer part).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
        \pgfmathsetmacro\half {0.5};
        \foreach \i in { 2, 4, 6}
        {
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\i*\half};
            \node[draw=none] at (\i,0) {$X_{\j}$};
            \node[draw=none] at (-\i,0) {$X'_{\j}$};
        }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do the calculations within the `foreach` loop with

```
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \moitie using int(\i/2)] in { 2, 4, 6}
```

see page 904 of manual 3.0.1a.

[image: half]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \moitie using int(\i/2)] in { 2, 4, 6}
        {
            \node[draw=none] at (\i,0) {$X_{\moitie}$};
            \node[draw=none] at (-\i,0) {$X'_{\moitie}$};
        }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```